# Approximating a summation over poles

Tags: summation, approximation

Given the following summation over a pole-like structure (or rather a summation over Lorentzians for $\eta > 0$)

$\sum_\limits{j} \frac{a_j}{x-b_j-i\eta}$

I'm interested in the following. Say that for some $j$ we have that a bunch of $b_j$ lie very closely together, i.e. fulfill

$|b_j-b_{j+1}|< \epsilon$

I would like to approximate these close lying "poles" by something more simple, preferably

$\sum_\limits{j=1}^n \frac{a_j}{x-b_j-i\eta} = \frac{\tilde{a}}{x-\tilde{b}-i \tilde{\eta}} $

Testing around a bit with Wolfram Alpha reveals that this approximation can be pretty bad if the $a_j$ are very different from one another but also reasonable if this is not the case.

Now the question is how to best determine the tilde parameters ($\tilde{a},\tilde{b},\tilde{\eta}$). For example just using the average of all $b_j$ for $\tilde{b}$ would be possible, but I'm sure I can do better by weighting these or so?

Comment: I have no immediate solution, just some general comment: it is probably wiser, if your initial problem is with Lorentzians, to keep expressions $1/((x-a)^2+b^2)$ instead of considering  a combination $1/(x-a+bi)$ and $1/(x-a-bi)$; otherwise, you will have to take into account separately that poles go by conjugate pairs. 2) It is surely valuable to begin by the 2 Lorentzian distributions $f_1(x)=1/((x-a)^2+b^2)$ and  (ctd...)

Comment: (...ctd) $f_2(x)=1/((x+a)^2+b^2)$ whose maximum value is resp.at $x=a$ and $x=-a$ and see what Lprentzian fits to $(f_1+f_2)/2$ 3) It is maybe interesting to take "probabilistic glasses" : Lorentzians (commonly called Cauchy distributions in probability), when linearly combined, correspond to what is called a "mixture distribution".

Comment: Thanks, thats a keyword worth looking into. For now I found http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3073-simplifying-mixture-models-through-function-approximation.pdf , which certainly goes in the right direction.